# Pandas 'SettingsWithCopyWarning' when accessing Dataframe columns using [ ] instead of dot

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

When creating a new column from 2 existing columns, why does `pandas` throw a `SettingsWithCopyWarning`

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

when running

```
df['c'] = df['a'] - df['b']
```

but not when running

```
df.c = df['a'] - df['b']
```

Furthermore, the `c` column is created using `df['c']`, but not when using `df.c`

---

`df['a']` is a `pandas.core.series.Series` of `numpy.float64`

`df['b']` is a `pandas.core.series.Series` of `numpy.int64`

Somehow when trying to reproduce this problem, creating a `df` from scratch with these 2 columns only, `df['c'] = df['a'] - df['b']` does not show the `SettingWithCopyWarning`!

Comment: What are `df['a']` and `df['b']`? as this may explain the warning

Comment: @EdChum `df['a']` is a `pandas.core.series.Series` of `numpy.float64` while `df['b']` is a `pandas.core.series.Series` of `numpy.int64`. Somehow when creating a `df` from scratch with these 2 columns only, `df['c'] = df['a'] - df['b']` does not show the `SettingWithCopyWarning`

Comment: My point was how were these created, if they are slices or copies, you need to post code that reproduces the warning

Answer (score 1):

That's ambiguous behaviour as you're accessing an attribute that doesn't exist so pandas will create one whilst the former explicitly tries a Key lookup, doesn't find it and creates the new column.

I strongly advise that you avoid using the dot operator to access the columns as it leads to strange and erroneous behaviour.

As to the warning it depends on what `df` and `df['a']` and `df['b']` actually are.